# OpenAI Gym: Understanding `action_space` notation (spaces.Box)

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I want to setup an RL agent on the OpenAI `CarRacing-v0` environment, but before that I want to understand the action space. In [the code on github](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/box2d/car_racing.py) line 119 says:

```
self.action_space = spaces.Box( np.array([-1,0,0]), np.array([+1,+1,+1]))  # steer, gas, brake
```

How do I read this line? Although my problem is concrete wrt `CarRacing-v0` I would like to understand the `spaces.Box()` notation in general

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`Box` means that you are dealing with real valued quantities.

The first array `np.array([-1,0,0]` are the lowest accepted values, and the second `np.array([+1,+1,+1])` are the highest accepted values. In this case (using the comment) we see that we have 3 available actions:

1. **Steering**: Real valued in `[-1, 1]`
2. **Gas**: Real valued in `[0, 1]`
3. **Brake**: Real valued in `[0, 1]`

Comment: What is the shape of `self.action_space = spaces.Box( np.array([-1,0,0]), np.array([+1,+1,+1]))  # steer, gas, brake`? Is it correct self.action_space.shape == [2, 3]?

Comment: I ran a test and it gave me (3,). So essentially `self.action_space.shape` returns the number of actions at least for the continuous actions, right?